# Typescript private member not incrementing

Tags: typescript

I'm doing a Typescript implementation of a familiar kata, the Bowling Game Kata.  Below is my Game class:

```
class Game {
    private scoreField: number;
    constructor() {
        this.scoreField = 0;
    }
    public roll(pins : number) : void {
        this.scoreField += pins;
    }
    public score(): number {
        return this.scoreField;
    }
}
```

It compiles fine, but when I test "score():"

```
test("AllOnes", function () {
    for (var i: number; i < 20; i++) {
        g.roll(1);
    }
    equal(g.score(), 20);
});
```

..for twenty rolls of 1 pin, I would expect score() to return 20, but it returns 0.  It seems that the scoreField variable is not being assigned to successfully.  After googling and searching SO for about 40 minutes I'm not seeing anything obvious...

Comment: Are you ever actually calling g's constructor?

Comment: Yes, during a setup function.  It's a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue actually lies in your test, you have this:

```
test("AllOnes", function () {
    for (var i: number; i < 20; i++) {
        g.roll(1);
    }
    equal(g.score(), 20);
});
```

But the value of i is never being initialized, so just try this...

```
test("AllOnes", function () {
    for (var i: number = 0; i < 20; i++) { // <-- note the = 0
        g.roll(1);
    }
    equal(g.score(), 20);
});
```

Comment: Actually, it's a property being initialized in a setup function.  It fails even if I move initialization to the test.

Comment: Nevermind, reread this--You're right.  Wow.  Thanks, can't believe I missed that...I'm surprised that it didn't report a crash.  I guess Typescript handles default numeric values differently than c#.

Comment: Yes, TypeScript/JavaScript initialize variables differently. The compiled TypeScript turns `var i: number;` to `var i;` and it has no idea if it is a number/string/date so it defaults the value to `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

> After googling and searching SO for about 40 minutes I'm not seeing anything obvious...

Based on your code 2 things need to work:

- the constructor needs to be executed ... this is not shown in the code you posted
- `this` can be wrong. If you did `var g = new Game()` (the constructor call) then `this` will be okay so probably not the cause. (more about `this` https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA).

Comment: extra credit for 40 minutes of looking (no pun on the incrementing intended)

Comment: The constructor is executed elsewhere in a setup function--it still fails even if you move the initialization to the test itself.